# Meteor Ionic Angular App inside a Package - How do you link to the template?

Tags: angularjs, meteor

We are developing our Mobile part of our meteor app as a package. Since we have mobile and desktop apps, we have a common core package, and the desktop and mobile packages are separate.

So we pretty much have an Angular/Ionic/Cordova/Meteor app inside a package.

The problem we are facing is how do I specify a path to the template. Normally when developing an ionic mobile app normally outside a package it works like

```
state('manage.prefs', {
   url: '/prefs',
   templateUrl: 'client/views/manage-prefs.html',
   controller: 'ManagePrefsCtrl'
 })
```

You see `templateUrl`? That is the path to the .html template that angular uses. Now normally if this was not developed inside a package the route would be relative to root meteor directory.

Since we are developing this as part of a package, the path is not working. We are using api.addFiles to add each template. But how do we get a path to the template? We have tried various paths but none seem to work. Is it possible to get a path to a template inside a package?

We tried api.addAsset which does provide a path but hot reload breaks and it caches all the files so you have to hard reset to make changes appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

```
templateUrl: '/packages/package-name/path-inside-package/manage-prefs.html',
```

Long answer:

There is now a new tutorial step for that:
http://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/angular1/mobile-support-and-packages-isolation

Comment: this works but hot code push is a problem. Please reference my issue here: https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/882

Comment: Actually we found out that the issue was google chrome caching the templates it seems.

We fixed this issue by going into the chrome dev tools settings and checking the box Disable cache (while DevTools is open)

Now the hot code push seems to work each time. Gonna keep testing and will confirm later.